# Can you render a single instance of an object through a partial using collections?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So for example, if I have a partial that works with @users as a collection, i.e.

```
<%= render :partial => 'dashboard/dashboard_pane', :collection => @users %>
```

where

```
@users = User.all
```

But DOESNT seem to work with a single instance

```
<%= render :partial => 'dashboard/dashboard_pane', :collection => @user %>
```

where

```
@user = User.first
```

The questions is, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use this partial with a single object, you should't be calling it with `:collection`. Try this instead:

```
<%= render :partial => 'dashboard/dashboard_pane', :object => @users.first %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's looping an Array.

Try with:

```
[ User.first ]
```

Comment: yes, it should work with every `Enumerable`. or use the `object` option: `render :partial => 'dashboard/dashboard_pane', :object => @user`

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is because it's not a collection :)

As @apneadiving said try putting it in an array. A very contrived alternative is to make it into a bona fide collection:

```
@users = User.find_all_by_id(@user.id)
```

I wouldn't recommend this though.